# The thumbnails for the product images are not displaying - Magento

Tags: magento

Look here:
http://wditestserver.com/live/jeanacarde/index.php/online-shop/f10-trx-fg-messi.html

Under the image there should be 3 thumbnails for other images of the product, but they don't show up. I checked the xml, phtml and css files associated with this section and also the product configuration settings but I couldn't find what's wrong.
Each of the 62 products has 3 images.

After I customized the product page layout (only with css) everything was well including the thumbnails, and as I worked in other parts of the website not directly related to the page in question, I didn't check it for a while, so only later I discovered the error; because of this I have no idea what caused it. The template support staff couldn't help me, either.

Here is a link to a product page of the templated the website is based on: 
http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/39249.html

I compared this page with one from my website, and I observed that the div "more-views" responsible with the thumbnails in not loading on my product page; I added the code for this div in other part of the page and then it is loading - but without the thumbnails.

I searched for answers on magento forum and stack overflow and I tried them but none brought the thumbnails back.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I met this problem in my app, I don't know if yours is the same but this could help if all your permissions are well (media => 775):

I had a **memory_limit = 4G** in my php.ini so I was thinking there wasn't any problem of memory... actually I was wrong because the GD2 library convert the value 4G, 64M or 128K into Bytes to be able to check that the image manipulation won't be problematic :

https://github.com/nexcess/magento/blob/master/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php#L83

```
/**
 * Converts memory value (e.g. 64M, 129KB) to bytes.
 * Case insensitive value might be used.
 *
 * @param string $memoryValue
 * @return int
 */
protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
{
    if (stripos($memoryValue, 'M') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024;
    } elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'KB') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024;
    }
    return (int)$memoryValue;
}
```

Because the value was expressed in Giga, this was trying to do a int cast to 4G which return 4bytes... that's is indeed not so much and Gd think so that memoryLimit will be reached.

Just changing the memory_limit in my php.ini from 4G to 512M fixed it.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is the file that render thumbnails in product view page

```
app / design /frontend / <package> / <theme>  / template / 
catalog / product / view / media.phtml
```

So in the directory specified above, you need to check whether this file exist or not.

Product view page layout is defined here:

```
 app / design /frontend / <package> / <theme>  / layout / 
 catalog.xml
```

There in  **catalog_product_view** handle, check whether *media* part exist or not

```
  <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <!--
           some codes here
            -->
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
           <!--
           some codes here
            -->
        </block>
   </reference>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The file in question exist and to be sure I  I overwrite it with the original file, although I don't remember editing it. The div with the thumbnails simply doesn't appear in the source code (unlike in the theme demo). It looks like the thumbnails are disabled from settings - although I'm not aware of the possibility to enable or disable them from the general settings. Only from product image settings we can modify their status and there all is like it was before when the thumbnails did show up.

Comment: your media/ skin folder has right 777 permission? Please check that

Comment: I set the permission to 777 for the two folders, but still no thumbnails. Can you please send me your email address to compendiumblogs@gmail.com so I can send you the ftp and magento dashboard credentials if you want to take a look?